# MySQL current_timestamp - timestamp throws wrong results

Tags: php, mysql

Hello in a PHP Script i have the following MySQL Query

```
$query_players = "SELECT (current_timestamp -`Online_since`) AS `Since` FROM `streams` WHERE `Team` = $temp AND `Online` = 1 ORDER BY `Viewers` DESC";
```

then i have:

```
$since = round($obj_players->Since /3600);
```

As you probably can imagine $since should contain how long the player is already online in hours. Strangely it has wrong results. Its like the time goes faster in MySQL :P 
For example after about 15 minutes it already shows "Online since 1 hour" another approximately 30 mins later it already shows 2 hours and so on.

Anyone know what could be wrong? Maybe current_timestamps is the problem?

Comment: What's the datatype of the online_since field?

Comment: You should really read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because seeing naked variables in your query is really a bad sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`current_timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) is not really measured in seconds. So dividing the difference by 3600 doesn't yield hours, but some arbitrary value.

The difference after 18 minutes is `1800` and `round(1800/3600) = round(0.5)` gives of course `1`.

Depending on your real column type use either [`timediff()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) or [`timestampdiff()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using TIMESTAMPDIFF:

```
$query_players = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NOW(), `Online_since`) AS `Since` 
                  FROM   `streams` 
                  WHERE  `Team` = $temp 
                  AND    `Online` = 1 
                  ORDER BY `Viewers` DESC";
```